# Arquillian Tests and Maven Profile

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian for tests in my project. I have created a maven profile which contains all Arquillian dependencies:

```
<profile>
<id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
 <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
 <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
     <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that when this profile is deactivated, the build server still tries to execute the tests which run via Arquillian and ofcourse the build fails. So, how can I make sure that when the profile for Arquillian is deactivated, the tests dont get executed.

Comment: you can add the following to your build "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"

Answer (score 0):

That would be because tests are annoted with @RunWith(arquillian.class) and thus runs with arquillian, In  the pom file you can specify in the build section to skip the tests that would prevent this :)